# How secure is using the applicationScope in an anonymous XPages application?

Tags: xpages

In a XPages application, I want to store some (confidental) information in the **applicationScope** to make it accessible for all users. However, the ACL of the application is configured such that anonymous users are allowed to read public documents. Still, I do not want them to have access to the applicationScope. Is it possible for an anonymous user to access/read the applicationScope?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the scope variables (including `applicationScope`) are *memory* contexts. The term "scope", in this case, refers to how broadly each can be accessed.

`requestScope` can be accessed by any code executing within the current page for the duration of *a single HTTP request*, at which point the object is destroyed. Any other pages, and any subsequent requests against the same page instance, have their own separate `requestScope`.

`viewScope` can be accessed by any code executing within the current page for the life of that page instance. Other pages -- including those accessed by the same user -- have their own `viewScope`. Similarly, if the user navigates to another page, and then navigates back to the previous page, that's a new `viewScope` because it's a *new instance* of the page.

`sessionScope` can be accessed by any code executing within any page during a single HTTP session. This is tied to session cookies in the browser, not to authentication. So if an anonymous user later logs in, it's still the same `sessionScope`. If they later log out, they still have the same `sessionScope` until they close their browser or the application clears out the storage.

`applicationScope` can be accessed by any code executing within any page within *the current application*. This is what allows it to be shared across users: If User1 is accessing `app1.nsf/page1.xsp` on one computer while User2 is accessing the same page -- or a different page -- within *the same NSF*, they have the same `applicationScope` -- the variable refers to precisely the same in-memory object for both users -- so any data stored via code executed by one user can be retrieved via code executed by another user until the application clears out the storage.

**BUT**, if User1 is accessing any page in `app1.nsf` and User2 (or Anonymous) is accessing any page in `app2.nsf`, the variable `applicationScope` refers to *different* in-memory objects for each user, because they are accessing *different applications*, even if there is code in either app that accesses on-disk data in the other app. The *in-memory* object that the `applicationScope` variable refers to is different in each NSF, no matter where any *on-disk* data it may access or create happens to be stored.

So *you* (and anyone else writing code in the same NSF) still need to be diligent about how you structure your logic to avoid storing sensitive information in `applicationScope` and then exposing it to users who shouldn't have access to it, but you don't need to worry about code executed from *other* applications accessing the same memory scope. Code can only read the data you store in your `applicationScope` if that code is executed from *the same NSF*.

Comment: thanks very much for the detailed and helpful answer. i knew that the applicationScope variable always refers to the corresponding in-memory object of the database the code is executed in. yet, i thought it might be possible to access this in-memory object from another database by executing something like session.getDatabase("MY_ANONYMOUS_DATABASE").getApplicationScope().....

Comment: There is no API call I am aware of that allows this. Ironically, because there are cases where it *would* be useful for apps to share in-memory info with each other, there are multiple extension libraries available that create a `serverScope` variable that is available to all apps on the same server... but even this is only accessible to apps on the same server. I couldn't, for example, write an app that connects remotely to your server (even if it allows anonymous access) and read your scope variables.

Comment: A critical point is that all of this information and code execution occurs ON THE SERVER and not on the client. For a user to inject SSJS code to be executed on the server requires designer access and probably Notes RPC access to the application. Notes RPC access requires a Notes ID which uses highly secure authentication processes.

Comment: The only exception to the above is when the designer has specifically included functionality allowing a user (or API consumer) to post code that is then evaluated by the application (e.g. using the `ValueBinding` API). If you're not specifically including this functionality, Newbs is spot on.

Comment: thank you all for your help, i got exactly the answers i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A user can only read values from applicationScope and other scoped variables if you expose the value through visible controls on an XPage. So if you do not expose the values, then a user (anonymous or not) can not see the value.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I'm more concerned about "untrusted" people getting information from my application (app). for example, an anonymous user can create his own XPages app and **programmatically** read public documents in my app. hence, i thought it might be possible to access my app's applicationScope in a similar way. Is this possible?

Comment: As Tim points out, applicationScope is only accessible from within the application (so from within code running in your nsf).